# Bootstrap DropDown Autoselect

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using bootstrap dropdown enhancement, is there a way I can pre-select one of the dropdown options based on a value pulled from the database?  I've tried the following which works for normal radio buttons but it isn't working for this.  I'm guessing because it's bootstrap it'll probably need some sort of .active or .selected adding in somewhere.

```
        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pri_email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Primary email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="pri_email" placeholder="Email" name="pri_email" value="<?php echo $row_ShowContact[0]['pri_email'];?>">
                <div class="btn-group input-group-btn">
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Home <span class="caret" style="margin-left: 4px"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><input type="radio" id="pri_email_home" name="pri_email_type" value="home" <?php if (!(strcmp("home", $row_ShowContact[0]['pri_email_type']))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?>><label for="pri_email_home">Home</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="pri_email_work" name="pri_email_type" value="work" <?php if (!(strcmp("work", $row_ShowContact[0]['pri_email_type']))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?>><label for="pri_email_work">Work</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="pri_email_marketing" name="pri_email_type" value="marketing" <?php if (!(strcmp("marketing ", $row_ShowContact[0]['pri_email_type']))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?>><label for="pri_email_marketing">Marketing</label></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" id="pri_email_invoice" name="pri_email_type" value="invoice" <?php if (!(strcmp("invoice", $row_ShowContact[0]['pri_email_type']))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?>><label for="pri_email_invoice" >Invoice</label></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The drop down in general works fine, and the `value` of `pri_email_type` is being stored in the database okay - I just want to be able to re-call it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself, with the above code as is I changed this...

```
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Home <span class="caret" style="margin-left: 4px"></span></button>
```

to this...

```
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"><?php if($row_ShowContact[0]['pri_email_type'] == ""){echo "Home";}else{echo ucfirst($row_ShowContact[0]['pri_email_type']);}?> <span class="caret" style="margin-left: 4px"></span></button>
```

Comment: That's not really autoselect. You're just changing the dropdown's trigger button label.

Comment: True, but with conditional present for each radio then 'checked' will show accordingly. So when you click on the button label, the correct dropdown <li> is already highlighted (and value selected).  All that needed changing was the button label.  If there's an official way to do it within the plugin then great, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: There are plugins designed for this specific purpose (such as [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)), but this works too.

Comment: Thanks Léo, I hadn't heard of bootstrap-select but it looks great!